# Kurento crash in video conference (audio only)

Tags: node.js, kurento

I've created successfully a video conference with Kurento/node.js and everything works fine with (audio+video), but I want to make calls with audio only, case a user don't have a webcam or don't want to use video. The problem is when I make a call only with audio, the Kurento crashes. I've tried mediaConstraints:{audio:true,video:false} but the problem persist, I think the problem is in node.js after create webRtcEndpoint when  I call webRtcEndpoint.processoffer.
I can't understand if is my problem or if Kurento don't allow audio only. Kurento is running on  Docker. I've seen a lot of posts related but I can't find a solution to solve my problem.

Comment: Kurento does allow audio-only calls. Are you able to see the server logs when the crash happens? What version of KMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 6.6
Log:

Comment: reconnect to server 9 5500 0b4894e0-4031-4a16-98a5-0a7bf330ab52
Trace: { [Error: Request has timed out]
  request: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"invoke","params":

Comment: {"object":"f6282311-2918-4527-90bf-3073b20e3b2a_kurento.MediaPipeline/1e4b102e-7154-4aed-bea9-3e5d3410bdfd_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","operation":"addIceCandidate","operationParams":{"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2940005878 1 tcp 1518083839 192.168.1.13 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag iYyC network-id 1","sdpMid":"video","sdpMLineIndex":1,"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate"}},"sessionId":"0b4894e0-4031-4a16-98a5-0a7bf330ab52"},"id":218}',
  retry: [Function: retry] }

Comment: I was referring the KMS logs. When the server crashes, it makes sense that there requests sent from the node app time out. You need to check which condition makes KMS crash.